# Xamarin SQlitePlatformAndroid() Missing

Tags: c#, xamarin

İ am trying to use SQLite and I can't find SQLitePlatformAndroid

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add the SQLite NuGet packages in your Android project and also add the namespace into the file.

```
SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **SQLite.Net-PCL** in all projects

```
  public SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
    {
        var sqliteFilename = "Test.db3";
        string documentsPath = 
       System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.
        SpecialFolder.Personal);
        // Documents folder
        var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, sqliteFilename);
        var plat = new 
        SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLitePlatformAndroid();
        var conn = new SQLiteConnection(plat, path);
        // Return the database connection
        return conn;
    }
```